# How can I bold each cell with minimum value for each column in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I want to bold cells with minimum values for one of my `data frames` which I combined to be one. I want the minimum value in each column to be bolded.

The below R code shows my Minimum Working Example (MWE). The table consists of columns of five (5) randomly generated values from the normal distribution. The first three (3) show when `std dev =1` while the last three (3) show when `std dev =2`. Each column is different based on its seed of generation and its `std dev`.

````
---
title: "Min Value to be Bolded"
output:  pdf_document
---

```{r}
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
  seed1 = rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  seed2 = rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  seed3 = rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 1)
)
set.seed(1)
df2 <- data.frame(
  seed1 = rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 2),
  seed2 = rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 2),
  seed3 = rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 2)
)
df <- cbind(df1, df2)
df |>
  knitr::kable(format = "html", table.attr = "style='width:100%;'", digits = 2, align = 'c', caption = "5 Random Numbers from the Normal Dist at diff set and std dev") |>
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = 'bordered') |>
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c('$sd = 1$' = 3, '$sd$ = 2' = 3)) |>
  row_spec(3, bold=T, hline_after = TRUE)
```
````

The output [image: looks like this]

Instead of me to get the minimum values **bold**. I got the third row **bold** all through. I can get the values on `R` like this:

```
lapply(df1, 2, FUN = min)
```

but I need help on how to get the cells bolded with `kable` or `kableExtral`.

Please note I do not mean to do that for the whole data frame, I only need it for just `df1` or `df2`.

Comment: html or pdf output? because specifying `html` in `knitr::kable` doesn't work with pdf_document. And which minimums do you want to see? Only in sd =1 or in both?

Comment: Please use 'sd = 1' and also 'html' instead of 'pdf' if that will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add `library(formattable)` and then

```r
df |> 
  lapply(\(x){ifelse(x == min(x), cell_spec(round(x,2), bold = TRUE), round(x,2))}) |>
  knitr::kable(format = "html", table.attr = "style='width:100%;'", digits = 2, align = 'c', 
                caption = "5 Random Numbers from the Normal Dist at diff set and std dev", 
                escape = FALSE) |>
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = 'bordered') |>
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c('$sd = 1$' = 3, '$sd$ = 2' = 3))
```

Or, if you only want for `df1` you may start by

```r
df1 |> lapply(\(x){ifelse(x == min(x), cell_spec(round(x, 2), bold = TRUE), round(x, 2))}) |> cbind(df2) |>
```

And for `df2`

```r
df1 |> cbind(df2 |> lapply(\(x){ifelse(x == min(x), cell_spec(round(x, 2), bold = TRUE), round(x, 2))})) |>
```

A remark: With my solution names of dataframe become all `x`. You could add `as.data.frame` after the `lapply` to get the original names, but in this case they become changed because `df` has the names duplicated which is not a suitable practice. Instead, using `col.names` you may write the desired ones, for example

```r
df |> 
  lapply(\(x){ifelse(x == min(x), cell_spec(round(x,2), bold = TRUE), round(x,2))}) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  knitr::kable(format = "html", table.attr = "style='width:100%;'", digits = 2, align = 'c', 
               caption = "5 Random Numbers from the Normal Dist at diff set and std dev", 
               escape = FALSE, col.names = rep(c("seed1", "seed2", "seed3"), 2)) |>
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = 'bordered') |>
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c('$sd = 1$' = 3, '$sd$ = 2' = 3))
```

[image]

Note also that as comment @phiver, I had to modify `output:  pdf_document` to `output:  html_document`, since otherwise code didn't work. To get a `pdf`, the last lines of the code should be as follows (then it works):

```r
  knitr::kable(format = "latex",  digits = 2, align = 'c', 
               caption = "5 Random Numbers from the Normal Dist at diff set and std dev", 
               escape = FALSE, col.names = rep(c("seed1", "seed2", "seed3"), 2)) |>
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = 'bordered', full_width = TRUE) |>
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c('$sd = 1$' = 3, '$sd$ = 2' = 3))
```